# Error message when installing ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to install `ggplot2` but get the following error:

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
>     namespace ‘scales’ 0.4.0 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.1 is required
>   ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘ggplot2’
>   * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/ggplot2’

Just so you know, I am using RStudio 1.0.136 and R 3.2.1 GUI Snow Leopard. Could it be a problem of compatibility with the old version of R that I am using? Does anyone know what the above means?

Comment: _‘scales’ 0.4.0 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.1 is required_

Comment: what does that mean? Sorry but I am relatively new to R!

Comment: it means you should update your scales package. See `?update.packages` for help.

Answer (score 1):

```
install.packages("scales")
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

will do the trick. Also try to keep your packages in R updated in the future, since R packages usually depend on the latest versions of other packages.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on windows try : 
`install.packages("ggplot2", type="win.binary",dependencies = TRUE)` else check the documentation in type and binary packages sections for the correct type according to your os :
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.5.2/topics/install.packages